# MATLAB code for object detection using a webcam?

Tags: matlab, arduino, webcam

I am using an Arduino to control a car and I want to make it autonomous by using a webcam to see the object I want and make the car move to this location. I need several things:

1. [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB) code
2. Interface between MATLAB and Arduino
3. How do I connect between them (software, not hardware)

I need any tutorial to learn or any instructions to make my project. I see many people have done this before, but unfortunately they did not mention how to start these kind of projects.

Comment: Cab you better define what you want to use Matlab for, because you can't run matlab code on an arduino.

Comment: @slayton - that's actually not entirely true.  MATLAB/Simulink provide deployment options which will automatically generate C/C++ code optimized for a particular target.  So though it is true that you cannot directly execute MATLAB code on Arduino, you can, in fact, develop MATLAB code or Simulink models for Arduino.  I believe that this does require certain additional MathWorks toolboxes, though.  This [link](http://www.mathworks.com/academia/arduino-software/) has more info on MATLAB/Arduino.

Comment: Just a slight correction to my above comment.  The C/C++ code generation is performed using [MATLAB Coder](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab-coder/) which (as I alluded to above) is not a part of base MATLAB.  However, the [link](http://www.mathworks.com/academia/arduino-software/) that I provided regarding MATLAB/Arduino refers to using a certain support package to perform interfacing between the two.  In this scenario I don't believe that code generation is being performing.  Additionally, it looks like this method does **not** require you to purchase any additional toolboxes.

Comment: @grungetta, wow thanks! I love it when I'm wrong, because it means i learn cool new stuff.

Answer (score 1):

This question is fairly broad, so I apologize in advance for my somewhat general response.

The easiest way to interface a webcam with MATLAB is to make use of the Image Acquisition Toolbox.  This [link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/imaq/f9-75080.html) provides documentation detailing how to do this.

There is a good chance that you'll also want to make use of the Image Processing toolbox in MATLAB to be able to process the acquired images to determine where to go. See this [doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/f0-3373.html).  Though, after you've determined more specifically how you plan to process these images, there are probably numerous algorithms that you could find online that would not explicitly require this toolbox.

As far as interfacing with Arduino is concerned, there is a support package from the MathWorks that allows you to interface MATLAB code and Simulink models with Arduino. See this [link](http://www.mathworks.com/academia/arduino-software/)

The only other general suggestion that I have is to consider using [Simulink](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/gs/gs_intropage.html) for this project rather than MATLAB.  I feel that the model based approach of Simulink is a much better fit when designing control systems.

I hope that this helps you get things started.